# How to remove words which contains same character more number of time?

Tags: regex, python-re

Here's an example input,,

```
text = "John Vv"
```

I need to remove `Vv` because it's same character repeating multiple times?

If the word contains other characters in it don't remove it, eg `VvSh`.

I tried something like this, which worked but I don't want to write same line for every english character out there, Any help is appreciated.

```
re.sub("vv", "", text, flags=re.I)
```

Comment: You need `re.sub(r"\b([A-Za-z])\1+\b", "", text, flags=re.I)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r"\b([A-Za-z])\1+\b", "", text, flags=re.I)
```

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `([A-Za-z])` - Group 1: an ASCII letter
- `\1+` - one or more chars equal to the one captured in Group 1
- `\b` - a word boundary

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8xkeEI/1).